# Django Template Skip 1 loop if the Value is Duplicate

Tags: python, django

I'm working with manytomany field because of various variant of product .But the variants are duplicating i can do the that in view.py but if any one can do it in template that would be really helpful

```
{% for z in variant %}
  {% for y in z.variant.all%}
    {% if y.type == x %}
      Title: {{x.title}} Code:{{x.code}}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

See these are the print

```
<QuerySet [<Variant_type: Size(Small)>, <Variant_type: Material(Polyester)>, <Variant_type: Color(Red)>]>
<QuerySet [<Variant_type: Size(Small)>, <Variant_type: Material(Leather)>, <Variant_type: Color(Red)>]>
<QuerySet [<Variant_type: Size(Large)>, <Variant_type: Material(Polyester)>, <Variant_type: Color(Green)>]>
```

I want one Red only one time same goes for any other

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{% for variant_type in variant %}
  {% with variant_values=variant_type.variant.all %}
    {% if variant_values %}
      {% for value in variant_values %}
        {% if value.type == x %}
          {% if not loop.parentloop.first %}
            <br>  <!-- Add line break if not the first variant type -->
          {% endif %}
          Title: {{ x.title }} Code: {{ x.code }}
          {% if not loop.last %}
            <br>  <!-- Add line break if not the last variant value -->
          {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

This should ensure that each variant type is only displayed once, and variant values are appropriately separated.

Output:

```
Title: Red Code: R001
Title: Blue Code: B002

Title: Small Code: S001
Title: Large Code: L002

Title: Polyester Code: P001
Title: Leather Code: L002
```